# How to change the frame rate of video

Tags: video, conversion

I have some footage with a weird frame rate of 57.19 fps. Is it possible to convert the footage to a frame rate of 24 fps? I know Adobe Premiere has that feature but does Blender?

Comment: You can use a speed control effect in the VSE to change the speed of a video, but I think you'll have to manually figure out what the right speed is..

Comment: I think that should work @gandalf3. The only thing is, what factor do I multiply the speed by? Is it 57.19/24?

Comment: Offer two ways to change frame rate: 1. Here is a tutorial on [**how to change Frame Rate**](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/frame-rate-converter-mac-and-windows.html). 2. Change Frame Rate with [**HandBrake**](https://handbrake.fr/). But it is a little complicate. No matter which way you choose, you will change the frame rate as your desire soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a speed strip in the video sequence editor. The one disadvatage of this method is that you will need to recombine your audio.

Steps:

1. Import movie in the video sequence editor
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Effect Strip*>*Speed Control*
3. Set the speed to Current FPS/Target FPS.
4. Render movie
5. Bring it back into video sequence editor, along with original. Hide the video from the original, and the audio from the accelerated strips.
6. Render again.

Comment: The problem is that then the footage is in slow motion. I was looking for a way to convert the footage to 24 fps keeping the same speed.

Comment: @Isaac, oddly I got the correct results when I tested this...?