# How can I avoid rendundant (no changes in progress) rendering?

Tags: rendering, optimization

I'm working on a project which is barely more than a fancy slide show, changing an image on a plane every few seconds.

The issue is that every time I render an animation, it does it frame by frame, repeating the same renders over and over again until the "slide" changes.

What I'm searching for is a way to opt-in to lazy rendering, where unless there's a known tween in progress, Blender just holds the frame.  Does something like this exist, and if not, is there any way to get Blender to skip renders?

EDIT:  I found this link ([Render optimization when frames are almost the same](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50468/render-optimization-when-frames-are-almost-the-same?rq=1)), but it's not very helpful and relates to similar frames rather than frames which are exactly the same.

Image for clarity
[image]

Comment: From what I see on the screen you are just overlaying a mask on top of an image. That can easily be done on the compositor, or even the VSE.  there is no need to use the blender 3D environment... Any decent video editing or compositing app would be better suited.  But if your concern is rendering faster then blender might not be the app you need. If you want to do this in blender for whatever reason then just load your image sequence in the VSE and use a speed control strip to get to the framerate you need. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/how-to-change-the-frame-rate-of-video

Comment: for clarity, there's a bit a shadow stuff going on, and at times the lights move around (like spot lights).  But most of the time, it's pretty static.

I'm going to try your advice, I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: one way could be to create just _one_ of those redundant frames (you have to know which), and render the animation to an image sequence. Then, "build" the final animation stretching each of those _single frames_ to make it last for more time (easy to do in the vse, just drag the frame end to the right)...